# c# - Cannot generate file with YouTube authentication tokens

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube-data-api

I’m developing an asp.net application for video uploading in YouTube which uses IIS server. A refresh token is needed for successfully uploading. The following code shows the method which should generate new file with authentication access and refresh tokens in a file path passed as argument:

```
private void SetRefreshToken(string refresh_token_path)
            {
               ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
                {
                    ClientId = this.clientId,
                    ClientSecret = this.clientSecret
                };

                UserCredential credentials;
                try
                {
                    // Approach 1
                    credentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        secrets,
                        new[] 
                        { 
                            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload,
                            YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,
                            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                            YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit
                        },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(refresh_token_path)
                        ).Result;

                    // Approach 2
                    //IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                    //    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                    //    {
                    //        ClientSecrets = secrets,
                    //        Scopes = new[] { 
                    //            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                    //            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload,
                    //            YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,
                    //            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                    //            YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                    //            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit 
                    //        },
                    //        DataStore = new FileDataStore(refresh_token_path, true)
                    //    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\error.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace));
                }
              }
```

When I start it, if I use Approach 1 - through "GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync" method, the execution flow freezes in the method. If I use Approach 2 - through "GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer" the code flow continues without throwing any exceptions but in fact there is no created file in the specified file path "refresh_token_path". 
When I start this code in a test console application it works fine in both cases.

Could you, please, give me an appointment what is the reason for this and how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: File datastore requires a path to where the credentials file is.  http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/  I would check and make sure iis has permission to access the path you have told it to write the file to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already read this article and I even had aksed the same question there but unfortunately, the answer there could not help me. I gave the IIS server full permission to access the specified file path: new FileDataStore(refresh_token_path, true), so the problem somewhere else.

Comment: I am assuming you are using 1.20 of the library?  any chance you want to try an older version.

Comment: I am using v.1.19

Comment: are you solved your problem ? .